# MAMP- Use local IP instead of 'localhost' in address?

Tags: drupal, localhost, ip, mamp

Is it possible to get MAMP to show my local IP address in the url instead of the text 'localhost'?

The reason I want this is im using the Drupal CMS which caches some absolute links to images. Im on mac so I need to test my site with a PC so I can use IE. If I type in my mac's local IP address I can access the site over my network.

However, the absolute links which use 'localhost' not the IP don't display.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to ask this over at serverfault.com, or superuser.com, since this is very much a "how do I configure my MAMP so that it is available on the network" question and has very little to do with Drupal or probramming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a solution. If I access the site on my local computer and type in my local IP, and then refresh the cache then the absolute links are created with the local IP. This makes them work on both my main computer and networked ones aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 99% sure that if you set up MAMP to work on port 80 you'll get your local drupal site from a remote machine on the same network (if you don't set it up on port 80 you'll just need to append the port number to the request ie: h ttp://1.0.0.0.1:8080/)

Comment: OK, Ill ask over there if noone know here.

Mirzu, thanks for your response but I think you misunderstood my question. My port is already 80, and I can already access the site over my local network. The issue is the url is different on the computer the site's on and other computers connecting to it.

Comment: can you use the external url to access it from the local computer? Also you should be able to set up a domain pointing to the computer you hosting from inside your network. It sounds like there is something wrong with your drupal setup, not with the setup of MAMP. Do you have localhost hard linked in these links or do you have localhost as the "base url"?